# android.location.Location setters not working as expected

Tags: java, android, location

I need to create a Location object from some latitude and longitude values, without going through a location provider. I do the following:

```
Location l = new Location("");
l.setLatitude(32);
l.setLongitude(43);
```

The values, however, are not set properly, since both `getLatitude()` and `getLongitude()` return 0.

Can you please tell me where is the problem? Isn't this the correct way to create a "custom" Location?

Comment: Hmmm... according to [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/location/java/android/location/Location.java), what you have should be OK. When are you calling `getLatitude()` and `getLongitude()`? Are you sure that you are working with the same `Location` instance then?

Comment: I wrote a simple ad hoc test where I create a Location and then check its values in the same block of code, so I can guarantee it's the same instance.

Comment: How truly bizarre. `Location` just isn't that complicated. If it's the same instance, and there's no intervening `reset()` call, I cannot understand how you are losing your latitude and longitude.

Comment: I also really don't get why Android Studio keeps telling me that the instance is null, when it clearly isn't: http://s11.postimg.org/55c5xjulf/Screen_Shot_2015_06_07_at_3_02_10_PM.png

Comment: I want to specify that I'm experiencing this issue only when running unit tests with plain JUnit. If I try to debug that piece of code with an emulator, it all works fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "plain JUnit"? If you are doing instrumentation tests, that should not matter. If you are doing unit testing (Robolectric, Mockito, etc.), perhaps the mocks need work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out eventually. When unit testing using the Android APIs, you need to use the instrumentation framework. I was using JUnit alone, thus the malfunctioning.
I resolved by using Roboelectric, a tool that sort of emulates the Android platform allowing you to run unit tests that use Android APIs without bringing up a device emulator every time.